# webcam "You have denied camera access" chrome + php

Tags: php, webcam

Estou com problemas em acessar uma webcam no site utilizando php aonde tenho a mensagem "You have denied camera access", o mesmo script no servido local de php funciona bem, não tenho nenhum problema. O hosting que estou utilizando é da HOSTINGER, e o browser é o chrome ultima versão.
Estive pesquisando alguma coisa e por exemplo o plugin https://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ ande pesquisando um pouco mais veja que tem que ter ssl pois o browser chrome pede essa segurança
alguém ja teve esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem em particular:

> You have denied camera access

Indica que você anteriormente negou o acesso a câmera para previamente para o domínio especifico, não é necessariamente ligado ao HTTPS, pra confirmar se o seu site esta bloqueado no seu navegador acesse o endereço no Chrome:

- `chrome://settings/content/camera`

E então veja se ele esta na lista de bloqueados:

> [image: chrome camera]

Se estiver clique no desenho da lixeira para remover, então na próxima vez que tentar usar a câmera no seu site provavelmente irá aparecer a solicitação.

---

### Sobre o HTTPS

Até aonde sei é impossível usar câmera sem HTTPS no chrome, então por exemplo, a função `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` não vai funcionar, fizeram isto para evitar que conexões não criptografadas pudessem ser interceptadas ou "atacadas" como em redes Wi-Fi por exemplo.

Conforme o aviso em https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/?hl=pt-br#acesse_a_camera_de_forma_interativa

> Aviso: acesso direto à câmera é um recurso poderoso e, por isso, requer autorização do usuário e o seu site precisa estar em uma origem segura (HTTPS).

Se tentar irá aparecer este aviso no console:

> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Para detalhes das APIs que requerem HTTPS acesse:

- https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

No entanto no seu navegador, e só no seu mesmo, para testes você pode adicionar um domínio permitido sem HTTPS, basta no icone de atalho do Chrome adicionar isto

```
--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="meu-site.com.br"
```

No entanto como disse é só no seu navegador, não vai funcionar para outros usuários/computadores, a não ser que a pessoa faça isto manualmente, a única solução é usar HTTPS ou um serviço de terceiros para trabalhar com vídeos e webcam.

Comment: eu não estou conseguindo entender como utilizar  --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="meu-site.com.br"

Comment: @edsonferrari como eu disse isso não é solução, não vai fazer a camera funcionar para outros computadores, essa flag tem que ser adicionada no atalho do Chrome, se for windows clica com o direito no atalho seleciona propriedade, então no "Destino" deve adicionar algo como `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="meu-site.com.br"`"

Comment: Sim amigo, entendi o que você ensinou, mas apenas para que eu teste, isso que te disse esta acontecendo no hostinger.
Hoje eu acabei comprando o ssl deles, paguei como boleto, mas somente na segunda feira provavelmente eles irão liberar, então queria ver esse solução provisória, somente isso, para ter solução de emergencia.

Comment: @edsonferrari tranquilo, então conseguiu alterar o icone do atalho? Depois de alterar é preciso fechar o navegador todo e ir no icone e abrir o chrome a partir dele. Boa sorte.

Comment: Sim consegui, mas não deu muito certo não, fiz exatamente o que você passou agora por ultimo, mas ainda a camera esta com acesso negado, mas mesmo assim fico mais aliviado sabendo que o ssl podera resolver meu problema, será que fiz alguma coisa de errado mesmo assim, para não funcionar esse "atalho"

Comment: @edsonferrari eu expliquei no começo da resposta, acesso negado é um erro, ssl é outra coisa. você conferiu a explicação de acessar `chrome://settings/content/camera`?

Comment: Sim, e não esta na no item bloqueado o site, no bloquear não esta nenhum site somente continua aparecendo a  mensagem que disse acima: You have denied camera access.

Comment: @edsonferrari pode mandar o link do seu site?

Comment: sim pega ai, e
http://www.residencialterraverde.com.br/movi_pessoas.php?id=71&token=f6266a8735b9b0fddfae7630431bba04
pode vasculhar a vontade se precisar posso te mandar os arquivos que estou usando para a web cam.
Esta também aqui aparecendo um link para mover para chat, seria melhor?

Comment: Amigo, como tinha lhe dito, comprei o ssl da hostinger, achei que eles iam só liberar na segunda, ja liberaram e realmente era o que faltava, esta aparecendo a imagem da camera, mas ainda tenho alguns outros problemas, mas que deve ser de conexão e outra coisa que aparentemente mas fácil de resolver.
A informação que você passou é VALIOSA, tem que ser HTTPS, isso eu aprendi aqui. 
TKS